# PyCharm is only moving one function per refactor command

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am using PyCharm CE 2017.1.5 on a Mac OS X system.

When I try to move more than one function per time with a 'Refactor -> Move' command, the IDE only moves one of those functions. In the dialogue that pops up for this, all of the selected functions are marked and in the preview dialogue it also seems, like the IDE is preparing to move all the selected functions.

However, only one function is removed from the source file and only one function is written to the target file.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Cheerio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24365) fixed in PyCharm 2017.2.2, [please update](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/index.html).